# ajax loading flash swf coming out empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, jquery-masonry, soundcloud

im loading soundcloud embedded players in  via jquery .load()

in IE whenever an swf is in it the load freezes and becomes incomplete.
if there isnt one the query works fine. it also works fine on chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```
function ajaxLoad(id){
    var url = "http://www.konstructive.com/projects/karlssonwinnberg/?page_id=118&cat="+id;
    $('#container').empty();
    $('#container').load(url, function(){
        $('#container').masonry('reload');
        Shadowbox.clearCache();             
        Shadowbox.setup();      
        //Masonry();
        ClickOptions();         
    }); 
return false;
```

}

object looks like this

```
<div class="item">
    <object height="571" width="571"> <param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F24256938&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork&amp;color=000000"></param> <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="571" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F24256938&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork&amp;color=000000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="571"></embed> </object>                        
</div>
```

you can check out the demo version here
http://www.konstructive.com/projects/karlssonwinnberg/

and the ajax load page here
http://www.konstructive.com/projects/karlssonwinnberg/?page_id=118&cat=0

is there another way to load flash using ajax?
any help is much appreciated